# How to print error if nothing is put in command line?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

If nothing is put in after java Rev, I need this statement to be printed "Enter only a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third."

This is not being printed but an error is coming up that says:

```
x-10-104-10-64:Assgn Katie$ javac Rev.java
x-10-104-10-64:Assgn Katie$ java Rev
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Rev.main(Rev.java:9)
```

What do I need to fix?

Here is my code:

```
public class Rev {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        if (checkDigits(num)) {
            num = subtractNum(num);
            addNum(num);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter only a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
        }
    }

    // checks if numbers are correct
    static boolean checkDigits(int number) {
        int reverse = reverseNum(number);
        if(number < reverse) {
            throw new Error("Reverse number needs to be less than the original number!");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //reverses number
    static int reverseNum(int number) {
        int reverse = 0;
        while(number != 0) {
            reverse = (reverse*10)+(number%10);
            number = number/10;
        }
        return reverse;
    }

    // subtracts
    static int subtractNum(int number) {
        int reverse = reverseNum(number);
        int total = number - reverse;
        System.out.println("Reverse and subtract: ");
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(reverse + " - ");
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(total);
        System.out.println();
        return total;
    }

    // adds
    static int addNum(int number) {
        int reverse = reverseNum(number);
        int total = number + reverse;
        System.out.println("Reverse and add: ");
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(reverse + " + ");
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(total);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of `args`. Add something like

```
if (args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("Please provide a single argument.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

to the start of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the 0th element of the `args` array, which may not exist (if the program is ran without arguments). You should either verify that `args` has sufficient length before attempting to access the element, or handle the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with a `try`/`catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/catch block with a print statement inside the catch portion to display that particular message.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {

        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        if (checkDigits(num))
        {
            num = subtractNum(num);
            addNum(num);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter only a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
        }
}
```